# matplotlib: get axis ratio of plot

Tags: python, matplotlib

I need to produce scatter plots for several 2D data sets automatically.

By default the aspect ratio is set `ax.set_aspect(aspect='equal')`, which most of the times works because the `x,y` values are distributed more or less in a squared region.

Sometimes though, I encounter a data set that, when plotted with the `equal` ratio, looks like this:

[image]

i.e.: too narrow in a given axis. For the above image, the axis are approximately 1:8.

In such a case, an aspect ratio of `ax.set_aspect(aspect='auto')` would result in a much better plot:

[image]

Now, I don't want to set `aspect='auto'` as my default for all data sets because using `aspect='equal'` is actually the *correct way of displaying such a scatter plot*.

I need to fall back to using `ax.set_aspect(aspect='auto')` **only for cases such as the one above**.

The question: is there a way to know before hand if the aspect ratio of a plot will be too narrow if `aspect='equal'` is used? Like getting the actual aspect ratio of the plotted data set.

This way, based on such a number, I can adjust the aspect ratio to something more sane looking (i.e.: `auto` or some other aspect ratio) instead of `'equal'`.

Answer (score 5, accepted):

Something like this ought to do,

```
aspect = (max(x) - min(x)) / (max(y) - min(y))
```

Comment: Well, that was simpler than I thought it would... Ever find yourself over complicating a problem :) ? Thank you farenorth!

Answer (score 3):

The `axes` method [`get_data_ratio`](https://matplotlib.org/api/axes_api.html#matplotlib.axes.Axes.get_data_ratio) gives the aspect ratio of the bounds of your data *as displayed*.¹

```py
ax.get_data_ratio()
```

for example:

```py
M = 4.0
ax.set_aspect('equal' if 1/M < ax.get_data_ratio() < M else 'auto')
```

---

¹*This is the reciprocal of [@farenorth's answer](https://stackoverflow.com/a/30559641/1730674) when the axes are zoomed right around the data, i.e., when `max(y) == max(ax.get_ylim())` since it is calculated using the ranges in `ax.get_ybound` and `ax.get_xbound`.*